# Best efficiency - Series branches within parallel or parallel branches within series

Tags: led, parallel, series

If I were to wire 25 LEDs, providing them with enough voltage to run 2 diodes in series without any drop in light output, would it be better to run a parallel circuit with 2 LEDs per branch or a series circuit containing two parallel branches (one would contain 12 LEDs in parallel and the other 13).

Would there be any difference in current output from the battery? Are there any tradeoffs/benefits from wiring either way?

Comment: The figure on the left looks like you are shorting your battery.

Comment: @relayman357 Yes, and unless I'm mistaken, in the diagram on the right whatever path you follow you come up against back-to-back diodes. In any case, even if your circuits were corrected, what is limiting the current through the diodes?

Comment: *Diagrams have no resistors included for simplicity* <-- circuit diagrams are expected to show all details. That is why we use them. A circuit diagram with things omitted for simplicity becomes something else (i.e. not a circuit diagram or a less than useful thing). BTW, as it stands neither of your "pictures" would appear pass current through the LEDs.

Comment: @HarrySpenser Please update the diagrams, the one on the right will never light because the battery is short. On the left one none of the LED's will light either because diodes are directional and all the current pathways will see no current because of blocking by the diodes. You also need the resistors because it matters where you place them

Comment: The plus symbol (+) next to the longer battery plate, indicates which side is positive.  If ever this symbol is not shown, the longer plate is always positive.

Comment: @relayman357 Yeah thanks, well spotted - This is now amended

Comment: @Andyaka 
Never did I mention not wiring in resistors.
They are ommited from this diagram because the question I am asking is unaffected whether they are there or not. They were created entirely for the sake of this post and are never intended to be used again. One could say for a theoretical implimentation

Let's replace all the LEDs with incandescent bulbs to make everyone happy then--
Is it more efficient to wire them in two parallel branches or a parallel circuit with two bulbs per branch?

Comment: @HarrySpencer incorrect, when your circuit diagram makes no sense in its simplified form, the un-simplified diagram must be shown in case your simplification has corrupted the diagram. And there's no point talking about incandescent lamps now; you horse has bolted and this question's credibility is degraded.

Comment: I said this in my first comment: "as it stands neither of your "pictures" would appear pass current through the LEDs." and, not showing 100% accurate diagrams (albeit them being incorrect) is the way in which people can analyse and tell you how they are wrong. Leaving stuff out is a recipe for not being able to analyse your faulty circuits.

Comment: @Andyaka See my answer- No resistors used, circuits working!
I will admit that the battery was the wrong way round on both of them which isn't particularly useful, however, even with the faults on the diagrams they still served as a good enough depiction of what I was asking; whether or not there was any difference in either combination circuit

Comment: @HarrySpencer: Without current-limiting resistors your circuit is extremely fragile.  There do exist other current-controllers besides a series resistor, but relying on the diodes to limit their own current is a bad bad idea.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, yeah I am aware- Purely a hypothetical, if I were to actually build this, current limiting measures would be implimented :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to expect the efficiency to vary.  If all the LEDs in each circuit alternative are identically lit, then they are drawing the same current/voltage in each circuit.  Therefore they are drawing the same power.  For one circuit to have a different efficiency then the other, you would have to identify "where is the less-efficient circuit losing the power"?  As you have described it, there are no other power-losing elements (resistors) in either circuit, so the efficiency must be the same.  Efficiency is just power_out / power_in.

Comment: Thank you! Ah yes that does make sense

I would suspect the circuit with two parallel branches would be the way to go then, as it's easier to wire it with an odd number of LEDs and if an LED fails in the other one, two go out

Answer (score 0):

After building the circuits on a breadboard, I discovered that both circuits have the same efficiency.

The parallel circuit which has 2 LEDs in series per branch would need to have an even number of LEDs (or the singular LED would need to be paired with a resistor) as having 2 LEDs per branch for every branch, and then just having one singular on another branch would cause only that singular LED to light up (as electricity takes the path of least resistence).

So the answer to achieve what I want (if I had to use only the LEDs, a battery and nothing else) is to do the series circuit with 2 parallel branches, one with 12 LEDs and one with 13 LEDs.

Correct Circuit Diagrams:
[image: Circuit Diagrams]

Leftmost Diagram Implementation:
[image: Parallel within Series]

Rightmost Diagram Implementation:
[image: Series within Parallel]

Comment: Likely downvoted by Andy who appears to be somewhat salty over I don't know what.. Computer Science student here, in no way shape or form an expert in electronics! Sorry if my diagraming isn't quite right first time 
Helpful answer by Atomique, which I also managed to confirm myself with the breadboard models!